# Strange Python error on Windows, works under debugger

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

The following code unexpectedly raises an exception: `pywintypes.error: (6, 'GetFileInformationByHandle', 'The handle is invalid.')`, i.e. `GetFileInformationByHandle` did not work.

The strange thing is that under a [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) debugger everything works fine. Even stranger is that when I remove `some_parameter` or `GetFileInformationByHandle`, the error goes away. This tells me that perhaps it is some memory error, but I'm really at a loss here.

Some of the code may appear to be unnecessary, but I can't shrink the code more without causing the exception.

I've tested this on Python 3.4.1 x64 on Windows 7, pywin32 218.5 and 219.

```
import os
import win32file
import pywintypes
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *


class BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('dwFileAttributes', DWORD),
        ('ftCreationTime', FILETIME),
        ('ftLastAccessTime', FILETIME),
        ('ftLastWriteTime', FILETIME),
        ('dwVolumeSerialNumber', DWORD),
        ('nFileSizeHigh', DWORD),
        ('nFileSizeLow', DWORD),
        ('nNumberOfLinks', DWORD),
        ('nFileIndexHigh', DWORD),
        ('nFileIndexLow', DWORD),
    ]


def GetFileInformationByHandle2(handle):
    GetFileInformationByHandle(handle)


def GetFileInformationByHandle(handle):
    bhfi = BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION()
    res = windll.kernelbase.GetFileInformationByHandle(handle.handle, byref(bhfi))
    if res == 0:
        errno = GetLastError()
        raise pywintypes.error(errno, 'GetFileInformationByHandle', FormatError(errno))


def open_file(path, param_1=False):
    return win32file.CreateFile(path, win32file.GENERIC_READ, 0, None, win32file.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, None)


def main():
    path = 'test.bin'
    open(path, 'wb').close()
    h_file = open_file(path)
    GetFileInformationByHandle(h_file)
    win32file.CloseHandle(h_file)
    h_file = open_file(path)
    GetFileInformationByHandle2(h_file)
    win32file.CloseHandle(h_file)
    os.remove(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You haven't indicated where the exception occurs (no stack trace). Also, is this the minimum amount of code required to reproduce the issue? Does it still happen if you operate on just one file, and eliminate the (seemingly pointless) `GetFileInformationByHandle2` wrapper function?

Comment: Yes, it is, without `GetFileInformationByHandle2` the code works. The code occurs at `raise pywintypes.error`.

Comment: To whoever cast that close and down vote, this *is* the minimal example.

Comment: This code isn't really all that long. About 1/3 of it is imports and a dictionary you can skip until you need to understand it, although it's interesting that the example included `GetFileInformationByHandle2`, which just calls `GetFileInformationByHandle`. lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This took me a lot of effort under windbg to find out what the cause was.

The problem was that `windll.kernelbase.GetFileInformationByHandle`'s first handle argument was being passed as a `DWORD` instead of a `QWORD`. The strange errors were probably being caused by the additional code modifying the first 4 bytes of `rcx`, which is the first argument in x64's calling convention.

I'm leaving this answer here for my own reference, and in case anyone else finds this useful.